# C++ system tray only program

Tags: c++, winapi, system-tray

After checking Microsoft's documentation on system tray icons (that I could find):

[Shell_NotifyIconA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona)

[NOTIFYICONDATAA structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_notifyicondataa)

I've noticed that a window handle (HWND) is REQUIRED. This is very bad for what I'm trying to accomplish, as I'm looking to create a program that only reacts to the system tray: it doesn't "minimize" the window to the tray, it just uses notifications (clicking/right clicking on the icon) to interact.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can create a window and never show it.

Comment: Oh my god, is this seriously how it's meant to work? Am I unable to pass a nullptr or anything?

Comment: The docs actually explain why you need the window: `A handle to the window that receives notifications associated with an icon in the notification area.` Only window's can receive events, so yes, you definitely need to at least create a hidden window.

Comment: @ZeroZ30o the point is that the window you pass is the target of the messages. It's not uncommon in Win32 to use windows just for message passing - there's even the concept of message-only windows (with no actual associated drawing surface or anything).

Comment: Indeed. You need a window in order for the system to communicate with you. Just don't show the window.

Comment: You can use a [Message-Only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows): "*A message-only window enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and does not receive broadcast messages. The window simply dispatches messages.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately, [a message-only window doesn't receive `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21141193/7571258) and other broadcast messages. So if you want to gracefully shutdown, instead of being terminated, a regular hidden window would be a better choice.

Comment: @zett42 good point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Windows 7 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) contains an example called [NotificationIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940367(v=vs.85).aspx). This example contains a line

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
```

in its `wWinMain` function. The effect of this call is that you see a program window.

Just change this line to

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

to hide the program window and only display the icon in the system tray. As others have pointed out the program needs a program window, even if it is not visible.

Comment: [NotificationIcon sample at GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/NotificationIcon)